# How to join 3 tables in MYSQL where 2 columns of every table have the same value

Tags: mysql

I have four tables and I want to get the `studentID` and `studentName` in the different tables that have a value of `yearLevel='Grade 8'` and `SY='2000-2001`

I've tried this:

```
SELECT b.studentID,b.studentName FROM requiremnetsforsecondcourses as b
WHERE b.yearLevel='Grade 8'
UNION SELECT a.studentiD,a.studentName FROM requirementsforoldstudent as a 
where a.yearLevel='Grade 8'
```

Table 1:

[image: Tables1]

Table 2:

[image: Table2]

Table 3:

[image: Table3]

Ive tried this also

```
SELECT b.studentID,b.studentName
FROM requiremnetsforsecondcourses as b
WHERE b.yearLevel='Grade 8'
AND b.SY='2002-2003'
UNION
SELECT a.studentiD,a.studentName
FROM requirementsforoldstudent as a
WHERE a.yearLevel='Grade 8'
AND a.SY='2002-2003'
UNION
SELECT c.studentiD,c.studentName
FROM requirementsfortransfer as c
WHERE c.yearLevel='Grade 8'
AND c.SY='2002-2003'
```

Result is 0

Comment: could you capture the result of the above query?

Comment: is there any issue with your query ? except missing SY='2000-2001' in where clause, it seems query is fine and you can union as many tables as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand what exactly you want to achieve by this, but here is what you can try -

```
SELECT b.studentID,b.studentName
FROM requiremnetsforsecondcourses as b
WHERE b.yearLevel='Grade 8'
AND SY='2000-2001'
UNION
SELECT a.studentiD,a.studentName
FROM requirementsforoldstudent as a
WHERE a.yearLevel='Grade 8'
AND SY='2000-2001'
UNION
SELECT a.studentiD,a.studentName
FROM `YOUR_THIRD_TABLE` as a
WHERE a.yearLevel='Grade 8'
AND SY='2000-2001'
```

Comment: Can you just run the single query without using UNION and see if they all are running successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM requiremnetsforsecondcourses as a JOIN requirementsforoldstudent as b
on a.studentID = b.studentID JOIN third_table as c on a.studentID = c.studentID where ayearLevel='Grade 8' AND SY='2000-2001;
```

Comment: This works but how can i make it 2 columns ? the student ID only and student name

Comment: @dods, replace * by a.studentID, a.studentName, then you can get the exactly as you wanted.

SELECT a.studentID, a.studentName FROM requiremnetsforsecondcourses as a JOIN requirementsforoldstudent as b
on a.studentID = b.studentID JOIN third_table as c on a.studentID = c.studentID where ayearLevel='Grade 8' AND SY='2000-2001;

Comment: if you find a proper solution of your problem, please make a vote to my answer